# Encoding double quotes in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

Tomcat disallows any presence of '"' (double quote) characters in URL, it is treated as invalid character as per RFC 7230.

However I have lot of service clients who are still taking to my service with URLs like `http://abcd.com/userservice?user="donald"`, I am looking for the ways to rewrite this URL to `http://abcd.com/userservice?user=%20donald%20`. I have to do this for multiple services (~20).

I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279681/mod-rewrite-replace-underscores-with-dashes but it doesn't help my use-case. Apache doesn't seem to let users rewrite query parameters. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying the client is not correctly URL encoding the request and thus sending an invalid URL? If so, then this is indeed a task for the client, as EsaJokinen suggests - after all, the request is technically invalid. Or is Tomcat simply unable to handle the quotes (even when correctly encoded) for some reason?! You can rewrite query parameters with mod_rewrite, but I don't think that is really the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a task for the client i.e. browser. If you type `http://example.com/userservice?user="donald"` to the address bar, it gets automatically encoded with the Percent-Encoding ([RFC 3986, 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1); mentioned in [RFC 7230, 2.7.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.3)), resulting the actual query to start with:

```
GET /userservice?user=%22donald%22 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

The `%20` you mentioned in your question is the same for ASCII Space character, `0x20`, whereas the `%22` represents ASCII `"` (double quote, `0x22`). Furthermore, literal `%` would became `%25` etc.

You could rewrite `%22` to `%20`, but I think this is rather just a mistake.

Just to be more complete, here's a chart. For Percent-Encoding, look at the column Hex.

```
ASCII Hex Symbol     ASCII Hex Symbol     ASCII Hex Symbol     ASCII Hex Symbol

32    20  (space)    39    27    '        46    2E    .        95    5F    _
33    21    !        40    28    (        47    2F    /        96    60    `
34    22    "        41    29    )        64    40    @        123   7B    {
35    23    #        42    2A    *        91    5B    [        124   7C    |
36    24    $        43    2B    +        92    5C    \        125   7D    }
37    25    %        44    2C    ,        93    5D    ]        126   7E    ~
38    26    &        45    2D    -        94    5E    ^        127   7F
```

Comment: I don't have any issues with the browsers since they auto encode, I looking for various web services which calls these urls. (I know that they are supposed to encode, but they aren't doing it). I am looking for an alternative in the interim while those services get updated to use new jar.